# Would it be correct to use a one-way anova or should I do a repeated measures anova?

Tags: anova

The experiment was about testing 3 devices on the same motorcycle that measured vibrations.

1 lap of the circuit was performed with the 3 devices mounted at the same time and the vibration was measured.

This was carried out 70 times in total, 35 on an indoor circuit and 35 on an outdoor circuit and on 5 different tire configurations.

The main objective of the study is to determine if vibration can be measured equally indoors and outdoors.

Also if these 3 devices separately measure the same indoor as outdoor and if they can detect changes in vibration depending on the tire configuration.

I have a doubt, the objective of the repeated measures anova is to check whether effects occur on the dependent variable on the same subject over time if I am not mistaken, but here in reality although it is a single subject, the same motorcycle, we do not think that this effect is important, but rather that it could be comparable to carrying out the experiment on the same machine.

That is, I don't know if it would be correct to consider it as different one-way anovas and T-Test independent groups, one T-test with all the data to determine if there are differences between all the data between indoor and outdoor, then 2 anovas to check separately if there are differences between indoor and outdoor for the 3 methods, and finally 6 more anovas, 2 for echa method, to determine if there are differences between wheel configurations for indoor and outdoor.

Would this raise any methodological errors?

Comment: Was there only one motorcycle used for all the tests?

Comment: Yes. Only one motorcycle did all trials.

Comment: Could you please title your question in English? This is English-only Q&A site.

Comment: sorry.... Done!

Comment: Some ideas about

Answer (score 0):

Because the "groups" are not independent, since they are all composed of the one and same motorcycle, you cannot use a regular t-test/ANOVA (which assume independent groups) and must use a repeated-measures version (or a mixed linear model).